# Is there a method to find the independant variables of a function defined in SymPy?

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-integration

I am currently trying to solve a very complex integral, firstly symbolically, and then by evaluating at different limits for optimisation.

For context, my derivative is the following:

```
dFx = 0.5 * row * Vapr * c *(Cl*cos(theta) + Cd*sin(theta))
Fx = sp.integrate(dFx, r)
```

Where, within dFx, the variables Vapr, c & theta are all functions of r. When I pprint the function dFx it is larger than the console.

Subsequent to integrating dFx for Fx, when I use:

```
Fx.subs(r,0.85)
```

This does not output a numerical answer, but rather then pprint(Fx) I find that the function Fx still has symbols of r in it.

Is there a function, which can tell me what the independent variables of Fx are?
Because the equation is so long, I cannot see it all in the console to check that only r remains.
i.e. something like

```
Fx.independants >> r, a, y
```

Then I would be aware that in fact, Fx is still a function of r, a & y

(For further context, I am trying to solve the Blade Element Momentum Theory equations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the [`free_symbols`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.basic.Basic.free_symbols) property:

```py
from sympy import symbols
from sympy.abc import x, y
    
z = x**2 + y
eq = sqrt(x) * y / z

eq.free_symbols  # returns {x, y}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only reason that I can think of that your `Fx` would still have `r` in it after integrating and doing a substitution would be because the integral was not evaluated. Consider:

```py
>>> from sympy import *
>>> from sympy.abc import r
>>> q = integrate(r*exp(r)/(1-r),r).subs(r,1); q
-Integral(r*exp(r)/(r - 1), (r, 1))
```

But this expression won't have `r` as a free symbol (it is a structurally *bound* symbol which can be replaced with anything).

```py
>>> q.free_symbols
{}
```

In this case you can see that `r` is still present by using the `has` method:

```py
>>> q.has(r)  # equivalent to `r in q.atoms(Symbol)`
True
```

So you know that your integral didn't evaluate or else substitution of `r` with a value would have eliminated the `r`.

Also, you can see if a known variable is a free symbol or not without generating all the free symbols: just ask

```py
>>> q.has_free(r)
False
```

How to evaluate an unevaluable integral is another topic.